# Getting Error Message when trying to install Chrome by command line

Tags: package-management, updates, google-chrome, dpkg, error-handling

I just reinstalled 15.10 because 16.04 crashed and would not boot.

These are the steps I did per the forum:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This is the error message:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable  
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: 15.10 is EoL, unsupported. Please use a supported release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its simple , just run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as directed by the error.